# Is there a way to not have a union "over-compensate" alignment?

Tags: c++, unions, memory-alignment

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
class Foo {
    union {
        size_t cap;
        char buff[15];
    };
    bool isHeap;
};
```

I would like `sizeof(Foo)` to equal `16`, but `sizeof(Foo)` is `24` on 64 bit computers. I think this is because `size_t` forces the alignment of the union to be `8`, and thus there is `1` wasted byte right after `buff` and `7` after `isHeap`. I thought of this solution:

```
class Foo {
    union{
        struct {
            size_t cap; 
            char ignore[7]; 
            bool isHeap1;
        }; 
        struct {
            char buff[15]; 
            bool isHeap2
        };
    };
};
```

But it relies on undefined behavior as you don't know whether to check `isHeap1` or `isHeap2` until you have already accessed one of their values.

**Is there a way to not waste those bytes that *doesn't* rely on undefined behavior?**

---

As a side note, I couldn't think of a really good name for this question, if someone can thing of a better one that'd be great. I will delete this remark if a better name is suggested, or if y'all think it's already a reasonable name.

Comment: Perhaps reverse member order and use `char isHeapX`?

Comment: "to not waste those bytes" --> also do not assume `bool` is one byte.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica why not?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but "`sizeof(Foo)` is `24` on 64 bit computers" is not necessarily true. It's up to the compiler to decide how to lay out data, and that depends on the characteristics of the target architecture and on the compiler-writer's predilections. It's undoubtedly true that the size is 24 on the 64-bit systems you've tried it on, but there are other systems out there where this might not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     struct {
>         size_t cap; 
>         char ignore[7]; 
>         bool isHeap1;
>     };
> ```

C++ doesn't have anonymous structs. This is ill-formed in C++.

> But it relies on undefined behavior as you don't know whether to check isHeap1 or isHeap2 until you have already accessed one of their values.

If the order of the members is flexible, then this would be a well defined alternative:

```
union {
    struct {
        bool isHeap;
        size_t cap; 
    } s1; 
    struct {
        bool isHeap;
        char buff[15]; 
    } s2;
};
```

This is the special case where accessing inactive member of union is allowed: Common initial sequence of two standard layout structs. In other words, even if `s1` is the active member, reading `s2.isHeap` is well defined and results in the value of `s1.isHeap` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `packed` attribute to the union to force it to be 15 bytes, then the containing class will be 16 bytes:

```
class Foo {
    union  __attribute__((packed)) {
        size_t cap;
        char buff[15];
    };
    bool isHeap;
};
```